# Foursquare API giving local names

Tags: django, api, foursquare

I am using Foursquare's [venue explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) option to get the city nearest to my user.

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&v=20141215&m=foursquare&ll=70.1234,28.234324&limit=2`

When I try the query in POSTMAN i get the country `Norway`
But when I run it through my terminal I get the Norwegian name `Norge`

Am I missing something here? How do I get the international name `Norway` from Foursquare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So giving an extra parameter `locale` specifying `en` solved my case.

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning#internationalization

Comment: R u sure that u get english name? I try different thing but it still show local name.